# Why did we study “defect” in the late 1800s?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, homological-algebra

I just began reading Weibel’s *An introduction to Homological Algebra* and stuck at the first page, where the author attempts to give a historical motivation for the homology construction:

> Homological algebra is a tool used in several branches of mathematics: algebraic topology, group theory, commutative ring theory, and algebraic geometry come to mind. It arose in the late 1800s in the following manner. Let $f$ and $g$ be matrices whose product is zero. If $g\cdot v=0$ for some column vector $v$, say, of length $n$, we cannot always write $v=f\cdot u$. This failure is measured by the *defect* $$d=n-\text{rank}(f)-\text{rank}(g).$$ In modern language, $f$ and $g$ represent linear maps $$U\xrightarrow{f} V\xrightarrow{g} W$$ with $gf=0$, and $d$ is the dimension of the *homology module*$$H=\ker (g)/f(U).$$

I am not seeing any motivation for studying the “defect” of the above phenomenon. Could anyone give a brief explanation for why did the mathematicians study how to write a column vector of $f$ by product of $f$ and another column vector? Much appreciated.

Comment: Why not skip the "motivation" and study the maths?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Till now I don’t have any “algebraic motivation” for the construction of homology groups. I guess I might get more comfortable with homology groups if I have more motivation to study it. I could be wrong...

Comment: If you want motivation, read any text on algebraic topology.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have read some algebraic texts and the only motivation I gain is that the homology group “counts the holes” of a topological space. It seems more appropriate to view homology group as a functor from Top to Grp that is homotopical invariant in my opinion. When I study algebraic topology I prefer to view a construction just as a “construction”...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know this subject, but you are right to ask if anyone has some insight (what you call "motivation") about the historical path that has lead in a more or less natural way to the discovery of such and such mathematical concept. New ideas cannot be traced back to older ones in only some rare cases.